# What's the difference between /\t+|,/ and /[\t+,]/ when split a string using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I have a string seperated by `\t` and `,`, but the number of `\t` is not fixed, for example :

```
a=["seg1\tseg2\t\tseg3,seg4"]
```

`seg2` and `seg3` is seperated by two `\t`.

So I try to split them by

```
a.split(/\t+|,/)
```

it print the right anwser :

```
["seg1", "seg2", "seg3", "seg4"]
```

And I also try this

```
a.split(/[\t+,]/)
```

but the answer is

```
["seg1", "seg2", "", "seg3", "seg4"]
```

Why ruby print different results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `\t+` inside `[]` does not mean "one or more tabs", it means "a tab or a plus". Since it finds two consecutive tabs, it splits twice, and the string in the middle becomes empty.

Most special characters, like `. + * ?` etc, when placed in an interval become "regular" characters. There are some exceptions, like `^` (which negates the interval when placed at the beginning), the `\` (that escapes the next character(s), just like it does outside intervals) and the `]` (that closes the interval; another `[` is also disallowed there). So, `[\t+,]` actually means `'\t' or '+' or ','`.

Unfortunatly, I don't know any reference for the full set of characters that need or don't need escaping inside an interval. In doubt, I tend to escape just to be sure. In any case, an interval will always match a single character only, if you want something different you must put your quantifier **outside** the interval. (For example: `[\t,]+`, if you also admit two commas in a row; otherwise, your first regex is really the correct one)

Comment: The full set of chars that need escaping in [] is the ones you mention: []\^ plus - (depending on position)

Comment: True. Interesting to note also that `-` is **not** a special character outside intervals, only inside, and between two other chars. And besides it, `^` can also be special or not depending on position (as the first character, it negates the interval; everywhere else it's a regular char). And most weird: `]` as the first character is allowed - `[]x]` matches a "x" or a "]". It's because of those many corner cases that I always escape when in doubt...

Comment: actually ] as the first char will give a warning, it's expected to be escaped in ruby regex, although many other regex engines do allow it.